# Get time from xts index

Tags: r, xts

I have an xts object, x. I want to run a for loop until a certain time, based on the time stamp in the index.

```
> index(x)
[1] "2011-10-12 16:44:00 SAST"
```

Lets say I want to run my loop as long as the time in the index is less than say 16:40:00. How do I strip out the time component, given the format of the index above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should get you in the ball park of where you want to  be. Using `format`, you extract just the hours, minutes and seconds part. Help page for `?strptime` gives more details about the symbols used for extraction of information.

```
#if you don't have your string in an appropriate format yet
(x <- strptime("2011-10-12 16:44:00 SAST", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
  [1] "2011-10-12 16:44:00"
class(x)
  [1] "POSIXlt" "POSIXt" 
(new.x <- format(x, format = "%H:%M:%S")) 
  [1] "16:44:00"
```

Comment: thanks, works a charm. one question though, in order to compare this time component to an arbitrary time, say 16:00:00, how would I go about it? I have tried: if(new.x > strptime("16:00:00", "%H:%M:%S"), but it does not seem to pick it up, as the new.x is an historic value and the new time has today's date

Comment: @E.D. I guess could create a new variable with date attached, or have your current variable with date as well.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is getting the timezone correct. On my system the `tz` spec of "SAST" is not valid but perhaps on yours it will be:

```
x[ index(x) < as.POSIXct( "2011-10-12 16:44:00", tz= SAST") ]
```

(Appears to be UTC +2. ) And I take back what I said about my system not recognizing it.

```
 as.POSIXct( "2011-10-12 16:44:00", tz= "Africa/Johannesburg")
# [1] "2011-10-12 16:44:00 SAST"
```

So use:

```
x[ index(x) <= as.POSIXct( "2011-10-12 16:44:00", tz= "Africa/Johannesburg")]
```